# Flow of influence in a v-structure for Probabilistic Graphical Models

Tags: hidden-markov-model, graphical-model, independence, bayesian-network

I'm not very sure I understand why an **observed** *v-structure* have different *flow of influence* behaviour for a *directed* and an *undirected* graph.

What is the *intuition* behind the actual definition for this specific case of *d-separation*?

So far I've been studying the *directed graphs*, or *Bayesian networks*. The "logic" behind the fact that two *parents* become dependent to each other once the *children* (*grad-children*, *grand-grand-children* or *grand-...-grand-children*) is observed is pretty straightforward.

Now I am wondering why this does not hold true anymore for the case of *undirected graphs*, or *hidden Markov models*. Is this "just because" there is no *parent-children* relation? If so, how does this affect the all?

Comment: In Markov Models we don't have any parent-children relationship. All we have is the neighborhood relationships.  Direct link in the MM specifies the dependency for two nodes.

Comment: This is basically what I said at the end of my question. My actual question is slightly more subtle. Basically, how does the absence of the *parent-children* relationship loses the flow of influence? Now that I'm re-thinking of it, it makes sense that since there is no hierarchical structure there is no way we can tell who is the cause of whom. So, it can be interpreted as the BN case in which an observed parent does determine the independence of its children. Perhaps now I got it. :)